# Extract till seconds in date variable

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to extract just till seconds and discard all to the rest of everything on right of seconds and assigning it to ExpirationDate1 but it is throwing me error . I am using postman to write the test.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var date = moment().add(3, 'days');
var ExpirationDate1 = date.substring(0,22);
console.log(ExpirationDate1);
```

Error message is

`TypeError: date.substring is not a function`

date gets value something like "2020-06-14T16:48:53.296Z" and i wanted to just have "2020-06-14T16:48:53".

Comment: Assuming this has missing `moment.js` tag, aren't you looking for [`.format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)?

Comment: Does `date` `returns` a `string`?, if not you cant use `.substring() ` on `date`

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `var date = moment().add(3, 'days');` is returning a date object. You can stringify it with:

```
var date = moment().add(3, 'days').toString();
```

When you receive that specific error, it usually means the data type of the variable is wrong.

Comment: That returned me  below for the value of date
"[Function]"